# In R studio, write the data into a file

Tags: r, file, transform

I generated a dataset in R and I want to write it into a csv file, but I can`t make it ,my teacher gave me the code but it doesn't work.

```
write.csv(myrow,file="bai.csv",append=FALSE,eol="\n",col.names=TRUE,sep=",",dec=".",na="NA")
```

The file name is bai.csv, the console showed that cannot change the dec.

Comment: So what is the exact error that you get?

Comment: cannot change the dec "."

Comment: Ok. So I guess the decimal is hard coded, as ".". If you leave that argument unspecified do you get the desired output? As in it saves it as a csv-file.